# Disable syntax highlight in Notepad++ but keep autocompletion enabled

Tags: notepad++, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting

I want to fully disable syntax highlight in Notepad++ but keep autocompletion and auto-closing HTML tags enabled. How can I disable only syntax highlight?
Edit: I want to do this for only one or few tabs, not for all files.

Comment: @harrymc I don't want to modify Notepad++ files and I have not option to enable/disable coloration in coloration tab (different versions?)

Comment: You may not want to modify config files, but if that is the only way to do this, you will not have a choice. So the question is: Have you tried the instructions given in the suggested link? If no, do so. If you have and they did not work, update your question (using the EDIT) button, with information about what you've tried and how it did not work.